# Escaping HTML for MySQL whilst retaining valid HTML structure

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-entities, mysql-real-escape-string

I have user content entered through a basic HTML editor. I need to validate this content and insert it safely into a MySQL database without changing its format.

Say my user content is:

```
$usercontent = "<p>This is my content</p>";
```

If I use:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($usercontent);
```

I get this inserted into the database:

```
%3Cp%3EThis+is+my+content%3C%2Fp%3E
```

But I want the literal HTML inserted instead:

```
<p>This is my content</p>
```

Is there a simple way I can convert the `mysql_real_escape_string` modified content back into normal HTML?

I should let it be known that I am modifying an already-written web app and I am not being paid to rewrite the entire thing - it's a quick debug I'm doing. Therefore I really do need to do it this way - I really need to store normal HTML in the database, just making sure I've validated the best I can before doing so. This also excludes combing through the entire app implementing PDO as an option too.

I've done some digging and I can't find an answer to this question... at least not explicitly... and anything on the subject seems to be wrapped up in lectures. Assuming I've read these lectures is there a simple short answer to this problem?

**EDIT**

It turns out my strange encoding was happening elsewhere and wasn't caused by `mysql_real_escape_string` at all. This makes my issue very unique to my situation and probably not much help to anybody. However, `urldecode` did indeed solve my problem.

Comment: not an option, @Drew - that would entail quite a significant rewrite. But thanks.

Comment: Again, @CharlotteDunois, this isn't an option because it would ential a significant rebuild of the app. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to get proper HTML

Comment: Are you suggesting `urldecode(mysql_real_escape_string($usercontent));` ?

Comment: Bingo! Tried and tested as above... works a treat. I had been experimenting with `htmlentities`, `html_entity_decode() `, `htmlspecialchars()`, etc. but I hadn't thought about using URL encoding. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> Say my user content is:
>
> ```
> $usercontent = "<p>This is my content</p>";
> ```
>
> If I use:
>
> ```
> mysql_real_escape_string($usercontent);
> ```
>
> I get this inserted into the database:
>
> ```
> %3Cp%3EThis+is+my+content%3C%2Fp%3E
> ```

Really?  You shouldn't.  As stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

> **mysql_real_escape_string()** calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: *\x00*, *\n*, *\r*, *\*, *'*, *"* and *\x1a*.

The escaping that you describe must be happening elsewhere.

Comment: You are right. I thought something smelled fishy! This content is actually sent via ajax from a jQuery script which serialises the fields on a form. I can't currently find where this unusual encoding occurs but, TBH, the previous answer solved my issue so I think I'll leave it there :) Thanks!

Comment: @Doug: Trouble is, if you don't know how/where/why the data is being escaped, it may not perfectly match with the unescaping provided by `urldecode()`.  Moreover, you should in any event `urldecode()` *before* applying `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: functions now switched... I will investigate further to see if I can spot where the encoding is happening.

Comment: It looks like the escaping is happening in the form's textarea - the content is being pulled from the database and `htmlentites` into the textarea. I think this then means that when the form is saved the content is already escaped.